# What is the difference between these two...one is fine one returns Nan

Tags: r

I keep getting an NaN error. When I look at what was causing it I found this:

```
-0.0283288347376038^(1/4)
[1] -0.4102581

(-0.0283288347376038)^(.25)
[1] NaN
```

I tested with and without the parenthesis. One works, one doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's how you placed the parenthesis.
In the first one, the `-` is out of it (no parenthesis) so the result you get is equivalent to `-(0.02...)^(1/4)`.

```r
 > -(0.0283288347376038)^(0.25) 
 [1] -0.4102581
 > -0.0283288347376038^(0.25) 
 [1] -0.4102581
```

You get a result because the `-` is out of the parenthesis

```
 > (-0.0283288347376038)^(0.25) 
 [1] NaN
```

You get Nan because the `-` is in the parenthesis, you are taking the quarth exponent of a negative number, which is not defined.

The `1/4` or `0.25` doesn't matter

Comment: There were no parentheses in the first statement. Are you saying that R treats `-5^(.25)` as `-(5^(.25))`? If so, that's really weird and interesting.

Comment: yes that's what i meant. That's the differences in the parenthesis (absent or before the `-`)

Comment: you can just try `> -2^2 [1] -4 ` to see how it is calculated without parenthesis compared to `> (-2)^2 [1] 4`

Comment: @divibisan It's actually pretty standard. I know several programming languages that work that way, and none that don't. And it's consistent with how "order of operations" is usually taught in math class, `-x^2` shouldn't be interpreted as `(-x)^2` in any context I can think of.